# Join tables with same keys, second table has multiple values for key and rows of second table must have same column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables with shared key and I'm trying to join them to filter data based on few conditions

tbl1

```
id    | OutPutValue  | 
1     | 2019         |
2     | 2018         |
```

tbl2

```
object_id      | status  |  type |
1              | 22      |  a    |
1              | 22      |  c    |
1              | 33      |  b    |
2              | 33      |  c    |
2              | 33      |  c    |
2              | 33      |  c    |
```

What I'm trying to get is : it must select all `'OutPutValue'` from tbl1 where, in tbl2 column `'type'` should be c, and column `'status'` must have same value for all rows i.e. 33. Note that Primary key (id) of tbl1 is foreign key (object_id) in tbl2.

Select column from tbl1 if, All rows in tbl2 (id of tbl1 have multiple rows (based on object_id) in tbl2) have same `status` value i.e. 33 and Type should be 'c'.

```
OutPutValue    | Type   |  status  |
2018           | c      |  33      |
```

I have tried with following solution, but it's not returning desired output :

```
SELECT a.OutPutValue FROM tbl1 a JOIN tbl2 b ON a.id = b.object_id WHERE b.Type =c
GROUP BY a.OutPutValue, b.status HAVING b.STATUS IN(33)
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried to resolve the issue, please?

Comment: @Paul updated the question with a solution which i had tried

Answer (score 1):

Try a join combined with an aggregation:

```
SELECT
    t1.OutPutValue,
    MAX(t2.type) AS type,
    MAX(t2.status) AS status
FROM tbl1 t1
INNER JOIN tbl2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.object_id
GROUP BY
    t1.id,
    t1.OutPutValue
HAVING
    MIN(t2.status) = MAX(t2.status) AND
    MAX(t2.status) = 33 AND
    MIN(t2.type) =  MAX(t2.type) AND
    MAX(t2.type) = 'c';
```

Comment: it's returning those rows too which are status != 33

Comment: @rohit Then add a condition in the `HAVING` clause to also assert this.  Your question did not make the status = 33 requirement clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using correlated subquery

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4ab79157733b26c5cacb2130538069d2)**

```
select distinct OutPutValue,type, status
from t2 a inner join t1 b on a.object_id=b.id
where type='c' and not exists 
      (select 1 from t2 a1 where a.object_id=a1.object_id and status<>33 and type='c')
```

OUTPUT:

```
OutPutValue type    status
2018        c         33
```

Comment: it will returns those rows too which are having type != c

Comment: @rohit, could you please show me in the provided demo?

Comment: your solution works but actually i am trying with, where `type` != value then select, in that case it's not working. i.e. type should not be 'value', select rest

Comment: @rohit, what you actually want to do?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be the following :

```
SELECT T1.id, T1.outputvalue FROM tbl1 T1
JOIN ( 
     SELECT tbl2.*, MAX(type), MAX(status)
     FROM tbl2
     GROUP BY object_id
     HAVING 
          MIN(status) = MAX(status) AND
          MIN(type) = MAX(type)
) T2 ON T1.id = T2.object_id
WHERE T2.type = 'c'
```

EDIT: I have updated my query to match a particular case which make it quite similar to another answer.

[**FIND A DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=03e222bc1be3e7e938225b815e76194d)